# Threading Example in Android

Tags: android, multithreading

I want some simple example on thread creation and invoking of threads in android.

Comment: You can refer to this post too : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148899/returning-value-from-thread

Answer (score 89, accepted):

This is a nice tutorial:

http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2009/05/painless-threading.html

Or this for the UI thread:

http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/commontasks.html#threading

Or here a very practical one:

http://www.androidacademy.com/1-tutorials/43-hands-on/115-threading-with-android-part1

and another one about procceses and threads

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

Comment: The first two links are not working..
For the first link, try
[link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html) 

For the second link, try [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: The answer is almost 1.5 year old. I try to update the links.

Comment: you are really nice to have answered an unspecific question such as this

Comment: I'd disagree that it is a non-specific question: it's asking the community for a very particular type of example, with a very particular focus.

Answer (score 11):

One of Androids powerful feature is the [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class.

To work with it, you have to first extend it and override `doInBackground`(...). 
`doInBackground` automatically executes on a worker thread, and you can add some
listeners on the UI Thread to get notified about status update, those functions are
called: `onPreExecute()`, `onPostExecute()` and `onProgressUpdate()`

You can find a example [here](http://android-jotting.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-asynctasks-in-android.html).

Refer to below post for other alternatives:

[Handler vs AsyncTask vs Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964011/handler-vs-asynctask-vs-thread)

Comment: .. I'm fairly certain your link is dead.

Comment: @While-E I'm afraid you're right

Comment: I've just updated the link. The blog has moved to this new location: [link](http://android-jotting.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-asynctasks-in-android.html)

Answer (score 9):

Here is a simple threading example for Android. It's very basic but it should help you to get a perspective.

Android code - Main.java

```
package test12.tt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Test12Activity extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        final TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sm);

        new Thread(new Runnable() { 
            public void run(){        
            txt1.setText("Thread!!");
            }
        }).start();

    }    
}
```

Android application xml - main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView  
    android:id = "@+id/sm"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/hello"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This seems to me like an incorrect example, since a UI update is being done from a background thread.

Comment: If you are updating ui thread you should use handler, because it's the middle layer between ui thread and your spawn thread , that way you will stay safe from dead locking

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html exactly discourages this kind of programming since it violates "Do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread" rule

Comment: I'm pretty sure in recent versions of Android it would not even work sometimes like this.

Comment: It violates the second rule of the single-threaded model: do not access the Android UI toolkit from outside the UI thread