# Broadcast receiver for incoming messages

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

If I have an inner class that extends BroadcastReceiver within my Service class, should I care about synchronization, when the BroadcastReceiver class reads/writes to objects from the Service class? Or to put it in another way: Are BroadcastReceivers onReceive() Methods started in an extra thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No by default all of the components use the same thread/process unless you specifically request the android system to use a separate process using the android:process attribute or create your own threads.

For more information refer to the following tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html#androidbackground_purpose

Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722974/threading-example-in-android) is same as yours.