# How to program outside the main UI thread

Tags: android, multithreading, udp, networkonmainthread

I don't know if a UI thread exists by default, how to create it if not, or how to tell <del>when I'm "in" it</del> where it begins and ends if so. How do I make sure `PacketListener` isn't part of the main UI thread?

I keep running into this **NetworkOnMainThreadException**. I understand that means that I'm trying to do something in the main UI thread that should have its own separate thread. However, I can't find much to tell me HOW to actually do that.

I had thought that the MainActivity class would BE the UI thread, since, well, I had a UI and it worked. However, I've created a seperate class that implements Runnable, and put the network connection stuff in there, and am still getting the exception, so it's still part of the main thread, yes? I can see that MainActivity doesn't extend Thread, so maybe that was a dumb assumption. I don't have the feeling that anything will change if I add another class that implements Runnable/extends Thread. Will it?

---

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ArrayList<String> listItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        (new Thread(new PacketListener(adapter))).run();
    }
}
```

PackageListener.java:

```
public class PacketListener implements Runnable {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public PacketListener(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    public void run() {
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

        try {
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
            socket.receive(packet);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            adapter.add("Exception: " + e.toString() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(Error e) {
            adapter.add("Unspecified Error: " + e.toString() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### EDIT:

My latest attempt, trying to follow [this page's](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes) example, has gone the route of most of my attempts, and broke the app completely. `SendAnother` is a testing method bound to a button:

```
public void sendAnother(View view) {
    adapter.add("button clicked");

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            listview.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    adapter.add("inside worker thread");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I think next I'll finally try `AsyncTask`. I no longer much care if it's "dirty".

Answer (score 1):

ui thread is main thread.  you know about current thread by

```
Thread.currentThread().getName();
```

sorry i didn't read your whole question but you have to do blocking proccess in another thread than mainThread.

there are many ways to do that : AsyncTask , Services , ExecutorService and RxJava .
and which one to pick depends on your need

[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4722985/6540997) would be helpful :)

Comment: Ok, but how do I create a new thread, separate from the UI thread? I thought that creating a class that implements Runnable would do that, but it doesn't seem to be. I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong, or if that's even a viable way to do it.

Comment: The long term answer is to google "Multuthreading in java"  then in android

Comment: Could you suggest a tutorial, please?

Comment: I appreciate your at least posting, as it seems to be something nobody else is willing to do (including on my other questions...) I would still really appreciate a suggested link though, as the stuff I've found with that search string have yet to be any more helpful than the stuff I've found on my own.

Comment: i'll do my best to help people : ) ... sorry for delay i wasn't online

Comment: Heh, yeah I figured as much, thanks. Currently revising the thread, shortening it a great deal.

Comment: Well, this didn't answer my question, but I think it may have played a part in helping me know how to tell when something has become a separate thread, thanks to getName()

Answer (score 0):

Your last method is correct, except the thread isn't started yet. So you need to call the `start()`:

```
public void sendAnother(View view) {
  //adapter.add("button clicked");

  new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      listview.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          adapter.add("inside worker thread");
        }
      });
    }
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: Ah, good point. No change though, it still refuses to run now, not even getting far enough to give me the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` I started the thread for.

Comment: Well, even my backups aren't working, and the completely new project I started to try to get SOMETHING working again is also broken. I have no idea what has happened, but maybe I should put this question on hold while I get this resolved...wheeee -_-

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure I like AsyncTask for this project, so if someone can offer advice or a link to a tutorial to use Handler or Runnable, PLEASE post it!

Strictly speaking though, this at least finally lets me do stuff outside the UI thread, and that was the question. Sooo, for what it's worth to any others having this problem, here's what first worked for me.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private static final int PORT= 8888;
    private static final int TIMEOUT_MS = 500;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);

        UpdateView task = new UpdateView();
        task.execute();

        //just to show these parts are in different threads
        String temp = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        adapter.add("onCreate: " + temp);
    }

    private class UpdateView extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
        protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            //just to show these parts are in different threads
            String temp = Thread.currentThread().getName();
            adapter.add("UpdateView: " + temp);

            byte[] buf = new byte[256];
            byte[] ipAddress = {(byte)192,(byte)168,0,1};

            try {
                InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddress);

                String message = "\"xyz\"";
                DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(PORT);
                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(message.getBytes(), message.length(), address, PORT);
                socket.send(packet);

                packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
                socket.receive(packet);
            }
            catch(IOException e) {
                adapter.add("IO Exception: " + e.toString() );
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return 0L;
        }
    }
}
```